# Laravel Eloquent fill method behaviour

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

The fill method called on my Eloquent Model doesn't update the object property, but instead allows the access to these properties as if it would be an array. Is this the desired behaviour, and if so, why?

You can run the following code in `php artisan tinker`

```
class MyTestClass extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model { 
  protected $fillable = ['testArrayProperty', 'testPrimitiveProperty', 'testObjectProperty']; 
  public $testArrayProperty; 
  public $testObjectProperty; 
  public $testPrimitiveProperty; 
}
$object = new MyTestClass;
$testObject = new stdClass();
$testObject->test = 'Test';
$object->fill(["testArrayProperty" => ["testKey" => "testValue"], "testObjectProperty" => $testObject, "testPrimitiveProperty" => "test" ]);

$object->testArrayProperty; //returns null
$object["testArrayProperty"];
$object->testObjectProperty; //returns null
$object["testObjectProperty"];
$object->testPrimitiveProperty; //returns null
$object["testPrimitiveProperty"];
```

Comment: you are 'filling' attributes not properties ... the attributes are the 'fields' ... we can access them via dynamic properties but we are not setting properties on the model.  in your example when you are trying to access the properties you are getting your properties not attributes because those properties actually exist ... if you did `dump($object->toArray())` those would be the attributes/relations

Comment: Thank you. I'm not quite sure I understand though,... Should I not declare them in the class definition (I tested it works)? Isn't that confusing? Are there any docs where this is described?